# Stepper motor has own encoder, can I connect encoder pins to microcontroller and see feedback?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver, python

I am using closed loop stepper motor with motor driver. Here is my driver [CS-D808](http://www.leadshineusa.com/UploadFile/Down/CS-D808%20&%20CS-D1008_m_v3.1.pdf). I am using this with microcontroller.

I want to stop this motor always certain location after 5 to 10 turns. I wrote a code, I am using (circuitpython).

```
for z in range (y):
    for x in range (1600):
        print(x)
        enaPin.value = False
        pulPin.value=False
        time.sleep(0.0007)
        pulPin.value=True
        time.sleep(0.0007)
```

This code is working. It is doing what I want. I don't understand two things. My stepper motor rotate 1 turn at 200 step (I calculated, My stepper motors step angle is 1.8⁰ ). If I wrote 200 instead of 1600, it goes like 45 degree (1 turn 360 degrees.)

- How can I sure 1600 is reliable and precision (so far so good, when I wrote 1600 stepper motor rotate 1 turn.) Is there another way ?
- I connected motor drivers encoder pins to motors. Do I need a microcontroller to get information about the step losses or precision of the motor? or motor and driver will handle by themself ?

Motor and driver connection :

[image]

Comment: *or motor and driver will handle by themselves* I would hope so if the driver accepts encoder inputs. It would be a [poor] driver if it accepted feedback signals and not use them for anything. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: What is the DIP-switches configuration?

Comment: (1) A short answer to you question is "Yes".  (2) Your stepper driver is very advanced, usually for heavy duty, mission critical industrial applications. (3) Ref: (a) CS-D808&CS-D1008 Closed Loop [8A peak, NEMA34] bipolar stepper Drive User Manual - LeadShine
http://www.leadshineusa.com/UploadFile/Down/CS-D808%20&%20CS-D1008_m_v3.1.pdf

(b) ES-D808w - ES-M23440w Closed Loop Hybrid Stepper Motor Driver - LeadShine US$150
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1901023675.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra. I can give you a longer answer if you confirm that you have skmmed the user manual.

Comment: @Antonio I am using first 5 switch on (default mode 1600 steps ). Thanks to you. I tried my code with 800 steps, It went 2 turn. Thank you i solved my code problem thanks to you.

Comment: tlfong01 , I read this. It says No loss of step , No torque reservation etc. So is this motor and driver do it without need anything ? If they do themself, should I use auto tuning switch on ? One more question , pend+ pend- pins 5-24 V output signal. So can I use them for information with my microcontroller ?

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome, (1) Let me entertain your first question: "So is this motor and driver do it without need anything?" , (2) I assume the "it" you mentioned refers to (a) "no loss of step, (b) no torque reservation, (c), (d) ... etc", and the list can be long. (3) To make our discussion not too TLDR, let us confine to the first thing "no loss of steps", which is often concerned. (4) In other words, let us shorten your question to the short from below: ***Can the LeadShine closed loop stepper motor driver prevent step loss by itself, without mcu?*** . Pls feel free to make counter suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering about this. And also I want to ask can Pend+ Pend- (5-24V might damage mcu ) pins supply feedback to mcu ?

Comment: (5) Quick reply to "Pend+/Pend- (5~24V)" _ Pend+ is open collector (to suit external MCU etc), so you can connect Vcc to 5V, and output should be 5V logic level. If you are using 3V3 mcu, you might need to shift down the 5V signal to 3V3. (6) are you using any 1000-line incremental encoders, or simple low resolution, for speed/direction checking quadrature encoders? (7) Are you using ProTuner to do the setup/calibration/verification for "in position" business?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134387/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-tryingtogetsome).